# Attribute 'XmlElement' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field, param, return' declarations

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting error,,,

> Attribute 'XmlElement' is not valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on 'property, indexer, field, param, return' declarations.

### Real Problem

I am trying to add a class as an element not as an attribute in a data contract but getting above error, is there anyway I can make "Settings" dataContract an xml element :-(

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class FruitCrate
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int id;
    [XmlArray]
    public List<Setting> Settings;
}

[XmlElement]    <---- it works with    "  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]"  just has problem with xml element but this is what I want.  
[DataContract(Name = "Settings")]
public class Setting
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int id;
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Fruit> Fruits;
}
```

Comment: To use the `[XmlElement]` doesn't the thing with the attribute have to be an isntance of an object, rather than a class?  I.e. use `XmlRootAttribute`.

Comment: thanks, but it didnot change any things

Comment: Why do you need a class (rather than an instance of that class) to be an element?  Can you give an example of what the XML would look like?

Comment: @MikeofSST I fixed the issue, but how ? I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed code,

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class FruitCrate
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int id;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Setting> Settings;
}

[DataContract(Name = "Settings")]
public class Setting
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int id;
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Fruit> Fruits;
}
```

I removed `[XmlArray]` from `public List<Setting> Settings;` and replaced it with `[DataMember]` and also removed `[XmlElement]` from on top of `public class Setting`

Why this fixed the issue for me ? I don't know, maybe you can answer and I will accept your answer instead.

Comment: It worked because, as the error says, the XmlElement attribute is not valid for a class declaration.  Essentially, a class is a type and more likely to be implemented in an XSD file, not an element.